# Dmax with multiple criteria

Tags: ms-access

I have an issue in Dmax code which i couldnt fix, please help me to rectify.

```
    Max_Rev = _
DMax("[Rev#]", _
"SCR_Run", _
"[JobNumber]=" & Me.JobNumber & "AND [Department]=" & Me.Department)
```

Thanks.
Muralidaran.

Answer (score 1):

You need a space between your job number and 'AND'

```
Max_Rev = _
DMax("[Rev#]", "SCR_Run", _
"[JobNumber]=" & Me.JobNumber & " AND [Department]=" & Me.Department)
```

Also if these fields are text, you'll need quotes.

E.g.

```
Max_Rev = _
DMax("[Rev#]", "SCR_Run", _
"[JobNumber]='" & Me.JobNumber & "' AND [Department]='" & Me.Department & "'")
```

or a combination...

```
Max_Rev = _
DMax("[Rev#]", "SCR_Run", _
"[JobNumber]=" & Me.JobNumber & " AND [Department]='" & Me.Department & "'")
```